# Set default program for custom file type via script?

Tags: windows, file-type, file-association

I've been given the task of writing a script that associated a program (lets say C:\foo.exe) with a custom file-type (lets say .bar). I know it involves editing the settings in the registry, but I have no clue how to do that for custom file-type via a script. Any ideas???

Answer (score 2):

You'll need two commands.

First is `ASSOC` which is used to modify file extension associations. It takes a parameter in the form of `.ext=fileType` where .ext is your specific extension and filetype will map to the actual command to be executed.

The filetype can be added with the `FTYPE` command which  modifies file types used in file extension associations. It takes as parameter `fileType=openCommandString` where our openCommandString will be the program to execute, with the parameters replaced in %1 etc.

Combining those two commands for your specific case will look like this:

```
  ASSOC .bar=Bar2Foo
  FTYPE Bar2Foo=c:\foo.exe %1 %*
```

Notice that you can run `ASSOC .bar` and `FTYPE Bar2Foo` to verify if the results are as you expect.